# How to create a Facebook post animation using css?

Tags: html, css, animation

Whenever I visit Facebook, this animation shows

[image]

before post is loaded. I think they use css on group of divs to create the supposed post lines and user image with background 
gradient

```
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #ccc, #fff 50%, #ccc);
```

However the gradient of the background of these lines changes with time. Is it possible to create this with css?

Comment: I am not asking to code this for me. I just want to know how is it done? What do they use?

Answer (score 4):

Despite it's old question here is [an article](http://cloudcannon.com/deconstructions/2014/11/15/facebook-content-placeholder-deconstruction.html) telling how to do it.

### The main idea

1. Start with a main white (or any other color) container.
2. Create a child container with animated gradient background.
3. Main trick: create a bunch of small white (or any color you picked before) blocks place them on top so they will overlap the animated one and create an illusion of different animated parts.

[JSFiddle full example](https://jsfiddle.net/Gendos_ua/d3cx4vzx/)

The hardest part may be the CSS animation, so I put it here:

```
@keyframes placeHolderShimmer{
    0%{
        background-position: -468px 0
    }
    100%{
        background-position: 468px 0
    }
}

.animated-background {
    animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-name: placeHolderShimmer;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
    background: #f6f7f8;
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #eeeeee 8%, #dddddd 18%, #eeeeee 33%);
    background-size: 800px 104px;
    height: 96px;
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: A link to a potential solution is always welcome, but please [add context around the link](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8259/169503) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline. Take into account that being _barely more than a link to an external site_ is a possible reason as to [Why and how are some answers deleted?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).

Comment: Okay, i'll expand my answer

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to create these kinds of animations with CSS3. Gifs are often used for loading images because all you need to do is include an image but they can be quite large and can take quite a while to load on the frontend. CSS3 however is much quicker to load so you can put it in anywhere.

In CSS3 you use Transforms and Keyframes to do the animation. A Keyframe defines the what the object changes to and from, for example the large and small versions of a pulsing icon. The transform defines how it moves from one to the other.

More information here http://www.sitepoint.com/creating-loading-animations-using-only-css3/

Comment: I think links are fantastic but should never be your entire answer: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/246338

Comment: I've edited it there. If that's more satisfactory can you remove the downvote? I ask you to keep in mind the person asking the question explicitly stated that they do not want to see any code

Comment: "the question explicitly stated that they do not want to see any code" then what are they doing on SO?